# Unity 3d - system.action<string> how to make it work in a IEnumerator?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my understanding of system.action in c#. I want the IEnumerator to print out the string in the method, how can I archieve this? I can't find anything on this. Ik know system.action allows you to pass a method, but how can I pass a method with a parameter, is this even the way to do it. And is there even a way to do it?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(test2(test("Hello World"))); // << also an error here "cannot convert from void to System.Action<string>"
    }

    void test(string t)
    {
        Debug.Log(t);
    }

    IEnumerator test2 (System.Action<string> _method)
    {
        _method(); // << here is the error how can I fix the syntax
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `test()` method up, and add a parameter into `test2()`:

```
StartCoroutine(test2(  delegate(string s){ test(s); }  , "hello world"));
```

and

```
IEnumerator test2(System.Action<string> _method, string message)
{
    _method(message);
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: I made 1 adjustment, briljant the second parameter!

Comment: @MikeOttink oh ya, wouldnt have needed to wrap the method up, what was i thinking xD

Answer (score 0):

This worked, thanks for the help Lincoln.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(test2(test, "whoehoe")); 
    }

    void test(string t)
    {
        Debug.Log(t);
    }

    IEnumerator test2(System.Action<string> _method, string _bla)
    {
        _method(_bla);
        yield return null;
    }

}
```